# Does PHP allow you to declare a Class variable without setting it up as a member in the Class definition?

Tags: php

I'm doing a code audit of a PHP project, and within the classes I have variables being declared within member functions without being declared in the Class definition, such as:

```
Class My_class extends Some_class {
    // no member variable in Class definition

    ...

    public function my_function() 
    {
        $this->someVar = 'someValue';
    }
}
```

This occurs all throughout the different classes, with no reference in the Class definition or any of the inherited classes, I would expect to see something like this:

```
Class My_class extends Some_class {
    public someVar = 'someDefaultValue';  // defined

    ...

    public function my_function() 
    {
        $this->someVar = 'someOtherValue'; // then accessed
    }
}
```

I've looked at the PHP API on [Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and at [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php#114443) and the closest example to doing this is dynamic classes, but they don't use the ${} syntax so that's not what they are doing.

If you can do this with member variables in PHP then they are just being lazy and I'll fix it, but I wanted to know this is the case for sure, and I wasn't just making an assumption.

Comment: Properties are added on-the-fly when you assign a value to them.

Comment: In general you should declare them, so that their access level can be specified (it's `public` by default). In turn, that access level generally should be non-`public`, though there are some legitimate uses for that.